# SQL fulltext-search with CONTAINS raises geometry error

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, contains

My php code generate a sql query as follow:

```
SELECT id, title, files, rating, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %M %Y') AS fancydate
FROM ArtArchive
WHERE CONTAINS (tags, 'Pepper')
ORDER BY date DESC
```

And it returns the error:
`HY000 - 3055 - Geometry byte string must be little endian.`

tags is a VARCHAR(255) indexed as FULLTEXT
I got the query to work by using : `tags LIKE '%Pepper%'`, so I'm certain the CONTAINS is in cause.

I couldn't figure out what this error mean, nor what I have to do with *geometry* of all things: I'm simply trying to find *words* in a *text*.

After checking multiple examples, I'm pretty sure that I've been using the correct syntax. I also tried things such as : `CONTAINS (tags, '"Pepper"')`, `CONTAINS (tags, 'Pepper')`, `CONTAINS (tags, "'Pepper'")`, with no different result.

I'm trying not to use IN or LIKE because I intent to search multiple values at once in the tags field. I've toned it down to one value in the example until I get get it to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does NOT support `CONTAINS()` for text searches, as you would expect:

> **MySQL only recognizes the CONTAINS SQL function when dealing with
>   spatial data. It requires two graphics objects as arguments**, and
>   returns a 1 or 0 depending on if the first object completely contains
>   the second. Designed as an implementation of the OpenGIS framework,
>   the MySQL CONTAINS function does not work on ordinary strings, and
>   will produce an error if you try it. **MySQL only recognizes the LIKE
>   and STRCMP functions when dealing with string of information**.

Found that info [here](https://blog.udemy.com/sql-contains/).

Comment: I was starting to feel that contains wasn't meant for text, but so many counter examples online kept me hoping... That's a bummer, but thanks for clearing that out, I don't think I could have found this on my own. So in the end I assume there is no better alternative than a series of `LIKE OR LIKE` ?

Comment: Yes, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html ... or possibly https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html